# How to add playlist in video.js in react-JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I have been trying to embed a video player in my web app. I am using video.js library for it. I also want to have a playlist like they have in YT or UDEMY or any other web app. So, wherever I try to read about how to implement it I am being hindered coz of documentation they have which explain how to implement it in HTML!! I may be getting confused unnecessarily but I need some help.

***MY CODE IS  AS BELOW:***

#### **App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import VideoPlayer from './videojs';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <VideoPlayer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### **video.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';
import VideoPlaylistPlugin from 'videojs-playlist';
import 'videojs-contrib-quality-levels';
import 'videojs-extra-buttons';
import "videojs-extra-buttons/dist/videojs-extra-buttons.css";
import "videojs-playlist-ui";
import "videojs-playlist-ui/dist/videojs-playlist-ui.vertical.css"
videojs.registerPlugin('playlist', VideoPlaylistPlugin);

export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.player = videojs('preview-player');

        this.player.extraButtons({
            quickBackward: { seconds: 3 },
            quickForward: { seconds: 3 },
            qualitySelect: [
                { bandwidth: 524288, name: "Low" },
                { bandwidth: 1048576, name: "Mid" },
                { bandwidth: 2097152, name: "Hight" },
                { bandwidth: 4194304, name: "Hight+" }
            ]
        })

        var videoList = [{
            sources: [{
                src: 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4',
                type: 'video/mp4'
            }],
            poster: "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png"
        }, {
            sources: [{
                src: 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/trailer.mp4',
                type: 'video/mp4'
            }],
            poster: 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/poster.png'
        }];

        this.player.playlist(videoList)

        this.player.playlist.autoadvance(0);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.player) {
            this.player.dispose();
        }
    }

    handleClick1() {
        console.log("Video 1");
    }
    handleClick2() {
        console.log("Video 2");
    }
    handleClick3() {
        console.log("Video 3");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="main-preview-player">
                <video id="preview-player" class="video-js vjs-fluid" controls preload="auto" crossorigin="anonymous">
                    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
                </video>

                //The div below is just the area in which i want to have playlist video's thumbnail
                //which on click will play the video connected to that thumbnail.
                <div class="playlist-container  preview-player-dimensions vjs-fluid">
                    <ol class="vjs-playlist">
                        <li>
                            <span onClick={this.handleClick1}>Video 1</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span onClick={this.handleClick2}>Video 2</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span onClick={this.handleClick3}>Video 3</span>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

#### Result: [image: ResultImg]

#### **Problem that I am facing:**

I am not able to understand how to use the [videojs-playlist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-playlist) and [videojs-playlist-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-playlist-ui) libraries to get what I want to achieve.
I tried doing it by link of videojs, videojs-playlist, videojs-playlist-ui and by this [blog](https://blog.videojs.com/video-js-5-s-fluid-mode-and-playlist-picker/) of videojs. Do help me.

So, first of all if any of you have any repo link or tutorial link that you can share that would be heavily appreciated!! But if you can help otherwise also, it will solve my problems too.

I am also open to suggestion if you have any other library which allows me to add some controls (forward, backward, previous, next, subtitle, quality selector, playback speed etc.) of player and I am being able to add playlist in it too.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

- The playlist plugin shouldn't need to be registered - just `import 'videojs-playlist';`
- The playlist UI plugin should be initialised - `this.player.playlistUi();`
- The playlist element should be a div - `<div class="vjs-playlist">`
- Playlist items should include `thumbnail` property for playlistUi to show an image.

Comment: Do you have any sample project or anything?

Comment: Your code with those changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-glitter-wkpk7?file=/src/videojs.js